# How find this maximum of the value $\sum_{i=1}^{6}x_{i}x_{i+1}x_{i+2}x_{i+3}$?

Tags: inequality, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, buffalo-way

Let 
$$x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{5},x_{6}\ge 0$$ such that
$$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}+x_{6}=1$$
Find the  maximum of the value of
$$\sum_{i=1}^{6}x_{i}\;x_{i+1}\;x_{i+2}\;x_{i+3}$$
where 
$$x_{7}=x_{1},\quad x_{8}=x_{2},\quad x_{9}=x_{3}\,.$$

Comment: I have edit it,it's $x_{i}x_{i+1}x_{i+2}x_{i+3}$,not $x_{i}x_{i+1}x_{i+2}$ Thanks

Comment: @communnites There is a proof by BW, but it's very ugly.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg   can you post your solution?

Comment: $x_1+x_3+x_5=x_2+x_4+x_6$.  Otherwise you increase the odds by one factor, decrease the evens by another factor, and the final sum increases.

Comment: You can swap $x_1,x_3,x_5$ around, and the highest sum comes when the lowest of these is opposite the highest of $x_2,x_4,x_6$

Answer (score 1):

For $x_i=\frac{1}{6}$ we get $\frac{1}{216}$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, let $x_1=\min\{x_i\}$, $x_2=x_1+a$, $x_3=x_1+b$, $x_4=x_1+c$, $x_5=x_1+d$ and $x_6=x_1+e$.

Hence, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ are non-negatives and we need to prove that:
$$216\sum_{i=1}^6x_ix_{i+1}x_{i+2}x_{i+3}\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^6x_i\right)^4$$ or
$$216(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2-ab-bc-cd-de)x_1^2+$$
$$24((a+b+c+d+e)^3-9(2abc+abd+abe+acd+ade+2bcd+bce+bde+2cde))x_1+$$
$$+(a+b+c+d+e)^4-216(abcd+bcde),$$
which is true because
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2-ab-bc-cd-de\geq$$
$$\geq a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2-ab-bc-cd-de-ea=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0,$$
$$216(abcd+bcde)=216bcd(a+e)\leq216\left(\frac{a+b+c+d+e}{4}\right)^4=$$
$$=\frac{216}{256}(a+b+c+d+e)^4\leq(a+b+c+d+e)^4$$ and
$$(a+b+c+d+e)^3\geq9(2abc+abd+abe+acd+ade+2bcd+bce+bde+2cde),$$
but my proof of this statement is very ugly.

Comment: maybe this last inequality have nice methods?

Comment: @function sug I tried, but $(a+b+c+d+e)^3\geq25(abc+bcd+cde+dea+eab)$ does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=(x_2+x_6)/2,C=(x_3+x_5)/2,tR=(x_2-x_6)/2,tS=(x_3-x_5)/2$.
The numbers are now $A,B(1+tR),C(1+tS),D,C(1-tS),B(1-tR)$.  The sum is
$$2AB^2C+2BC^2D+2ABCD-2t^2(AB^2CR^2+BC^2DS^2-ABCDRS)$$
Let $t$ vary.  The maximum is either when $t=0$ or when $t$ is as large as possible.

$t$ is at its largest when $B(1-tR)$ or $C(1-tS)$ has reached zero.  It is simple to calculate the sum's maximum when one value is zero; that maximum is $1/256$.

If the maximum is when $t=0$, then the numbers are $A,B,C,D,C,B$.  That is, $x_2=x_6$ and $x_3=x_5$.
A similar argument shows that any maximum other than $1/256$ has $x_2=x_4$ and $x_1=x_5$.
So the numbers are $C,B,C,B,C,B$ and the sum is $6B^2C^2$.  That is maximum when $B=C=1/6$, and the sum is $1/216$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1=a,\ x_2=b,\ x_3=c,\ x_4=d,\ x_5=e,\ x_6=f.$

Objective function is
$$Z(a,b,c,d,e,f) = abcd + bcde + cdef + defa + efab + fabc.$$

Let maximize $Z(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ using Lagrange mulptiplyers method for the function 
$$F(a,b,c,d,e,f,\lambda) = abcd + bcde + cdef + defa + efab + fabc + \lambda(1-a-b-c-d-e-f).$$
Equaling to zero partial derivatives $F'_a,\ F'_b,\ F'_c,\ F'_d,\ F'_e,\ F'_f,\ $ one can obtain the system:
$$\begin{cases}
bcd+bcf+bef+def = \lambda\\
acd+acf+aef+cde = \lambda\\
abd+abf+bde+def = \lambda\\
abc+aef+bce+cef = \lambda\\
abf+adf+bcd+cdf = \lambda\\
abc+abe+ade+cde = \lambda\\
a+b+c+d+e+f = 1.
\end{cases}$$

Note that:

1. First and third equations contains the common term $def.$
2. Second and fourth - $aef.$
3. Third and fifth - $abf.$
4. Fourth and six - $abc.$
5. Fifth and first - $bcd.$
6. Sixth and second - $cde.$

So
$$\begin{cases}
bcd+bcf+bef = abd+abf+bde\qquad(1)\\
acd+acf+cde = abc+bce+cef\qquad(2)\\
abd+bde+def = adf+bcd+cdf\qquad(3)\\
aef+bce+cef = abe+ade+cde\qquad(4)\\
abf+adf+cdf = bcf+bef+def\qquad(5)\\
abc+abe+ade = acd+acf+aef\qquad(6)\\
a+b+c+d+e+f = 1.\qquad\qquad\qquad(7)
\end{cases}$$

Easy to see that:

1. Both $Z(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ and accordingly the system $(1-7)$ WLOG allows any cyclic permutation of $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$.
2. Substitution of any pair of zero unknowns equals objective function to zero if that unknowns are not neighbours in the list of unknowns.

Let us consider zero cases in detail.

**"Neighbouring zeros" case $b=c=0$ (and cyclic permutations).**

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ give $LHS=RHS=0,$ remaining equations can be simplified to the form of 
$$a=e,\quad d=f,\quad a+d = \frac12,$$
with the object function 
$$Z(a, 0, 0, d, a, d) = a^2\left(\frac12-a\right)^2\quad\text{for } a\in\left(0,\dfrac12\right).$$
That gives
$$Z_{max} = \frac1{256}\text{ for } a=\frac14.$$

**"Single zero" case $b=0, a>0, c>0.$ (and cyclic permutations).**

And condition $Z>0$ requires $d>0, e>0, f>0.$

The equations $(3,4,6)$ forms a system
$$\begin{cases}
def = adf+cdf\\
aef+cef = ade+cde\\
ade = acd+acf+aef
\end{cases}\rightarrow
\begin{cases}
e = a+c\\
(a+c)f = (a+c)d\\
de = cd+cf+ef,
\end{cases}$$

$ef=de,\ c(d+f)=0.$

This contradicts the conditions $c>0,\ d>0,\ f>0.$

**Case $abcdef>0.$**

This case allows reduction of $(1-6)$:

$$\begin{cases}
cd+cf+ef = ad+af+de\qquad(1a)\\
ad+af+de = ab+be+ef\qquad(2a)\\
ab+be+ef = af+bc+cf\qquad(3a)\\
af+bc+cf = ab+ad+cd\qquad(4a)\\
ab+ad+cd = bc+be+de\qquad(5a)\\
bc+be+de = cd+cf+ef\qquad(6a)\\
a+b+c+d+e+f = 1.\qquad\quad(7)
\end{cases}$$

Summations $(1a+2a),\ (2a+3a),\ (3a+4a),\ (4a+5a),\ (5a+6a),\ $ leads to the system

$$\begin{cases}
cd+cf = ab+be\qquad\qquad(1b)\\
ad+de = bc+cf\qquad\qquad(2b)\\
be+ef = ad+cd\qquad\qquad(3b)\\
af+cf = be+de\qquad\qquad(4b)\\
ab+ad = cf+ef\qquad\qquad(5b)\\
a+b+c+d+e+f = 1.\quad(7)
\end{cases}$$

Now weighted sums $(1b)\cdot d+(2b)\cdot b,$ $(2b)\cdot e+(3b)\cdot,$ $(3b)\cdot f+(4b)\cdot d,$ $(4b)\cdot a+(5b)\cdot c$ form the system

$$\begin{cases}
cd^2+cdf = b^2c+bcf\\
ade+de^2 = acd+c^2d\\
bef+ef^2 = bde+d^2e\\
a^2f+acf = cef+e^2f\\
a+b+c+d+e+f = 1
\end{cases}\rightarrow
\begin{cases}
(d-b)\cdot(b+d+f) = 0\\
(e-c)\cdot(c+e+a) = 0\\
(f-d)\cdot(f+d+b) = 0\\
(a-e)\cdot(a+e+c) = 0\\
a+b+c+d+e+f = 1
\end{cases}$$

$$f=d=b,\quad e=c=a,\quad a+b = \dfrac13.$$
The object function is
$$Z(a, b, a, b,a,b) = 6a^3\left(\dfrac13 - a\right)^3$$ 
for $a\in\left(0,\dfrac13\right)$.

That gives
$$Z_{max}(a) = \frac1{216}\text{ for } a=\frac16,$$
and finally
$$\boxed{\max Z(\vec x) = \dfrac 1{216}\quad\text{ for all }x_i=\dfrac16.}$$