# How prove this inequality $(a+b+c+d+e)^3\geq9(2abc+abd+abe+acd+ade+2bcd+bce+bde+2cde),$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c,d$ and $,e$ are non-negatives .show that

$$(a+b+c+d+e)^3\geq9(2abc+abd+abe+acd+ade+2bcd+bce+bde+2cde),$$

[Michael Rozenberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/190319/michael-rozenberg) says that this inequality proof is very ugly.

I think this inequality seems nice and maybe it has *simple* methods to solve it?

Comment: Most inequalities I've seen here are not so nice and do not not have simple methods to solve.

Comment: For conext, the source of this question is http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2201085 (as I found in the edit history). It's too late now, but I would have suggested that you put you bounty directly over there, which I presume is the question you actually care about. It's much nicer than this, which does not seem nice at all

Comment: Maybe you could compute all partial derivatives to show that after some value $a+b+c+d+e=x$, $(a+b+c+d+e)^{3}$ is growing faster than messy RHS, then just check the finite cases directly, hopefully there are not many.

Comment: @echinodermata There are two different questions.Issue question has a nice form and routine way to solution, and this vice versa.

Comment: @Morph It is much easier to apply the method of Lagrange multipliers to the [original equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201085/how-find-this-maximum-of-the-value-sum-i-16x-ix-i1x-i2x-i3/2227556#2227556). But it's not so interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first, from AM-GM:
$$\frac13(a+b+c+d+e)^3 \ge 9(a+b)c(d+e) = 9(acd+bcd+ace+bce),$$
and similarly for any permutations of $a,b,c,d,e.$
So it requres to find only 3 of them, the sum of which gives RHS of original inequality.

Taking in account that RHS of original inequality doesn'n contain the term $ace,$ one can obtain only 9 variants of satisfying permutations.
One of its combinations can lead to goal.

Easy to see that there are only 6 pairs of permutations which gives the term $2abc$ in sum. Third permutation can be found among another permutations.

Checking of them with Google Sheets gives required triple.
[image: picture]

Finally,
$$(a+b+c+d+e)^3 \ge 9((a+c)d(b+e) + (a+e)c(b+d) + (c+e)b(a+d)),$$
$$\boxed{(a+b+c+d+e)^3\geq9(2abc+abd+abe+acd+ade+2bcd+bce+bde+2cde).}$$

Comment: My congratulations!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you! At first I thought that the question was specially thought out. And only then I saw how it came out of the [routine task](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201085/how-find-this-maximum-of-the-value-sum-i-16x-ix-i1x-i2x-i3/2227556#2227556) with the help of "bw".